# Sitecore Forms 10.2 client validation

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have Sitecore Forms 10.2 installed, and I am trying to create form with basic validations like required fields, and fields that should not be empty.

I created a form, added single line text fields, and set them as mandatory

[image]

Now, when I click on submit, I need the form to show the validation message below each field that it is required without doing a postback and redirecting the user to another page with the form and the validation.. Something that looks like this:

[image]

Is that possible? Kindly assist

When I click submit, it redirects me to the following page, and there it shows the validation messages:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked `Is Ajax` on the form?

Comment: yes "Ajax enabled" is checked

Comment: And what happens when you click submit?

Comment: Is it doing postback when you click on submit?

Comment: Yes, when i click on submit, it redirects me to the following page "kindly check the screenshot I added above in the post" and there it shows that those fields are required..

Comment: Are there any javascript console errors when you load the page with the form on it?

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: I can't see MVC Layout in Sitecore 10.2.. the link you sent is for sitecore 9 forms..